# Android emulator - asking for login details everytime

Tags: android, emulation, android-virtual-device

I'm currently testing an Android APP.
After the first login, the App should keep me logged when i close it and reopen it.
This works fine with my personal android phone, however, when using android emulator with the same android version, everytime i reopen the app, it asks for login details.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am sure it is not an emulator problem. You should post some code.

Comment: @hata I don't think this is the problem, because he just closes application.

Comment: @AlexRmcf I see, thank you. I totally mistook

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.